# Magento images are not showing up - case sensitive filename

Tags: configurable-product, image, importexport

I transferred Magento shopping cart one server to another server after that 
my site product images are not showing on the new site.

All images **/media/catalog/product/A/S/As-1_3.JPG** in ftp

but img src call it as **/media/catalog/product/a/s/as-1_3.jpg**

I am wondering how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you've moved from a Windows server to a Linux server.

Most Windows file systems are not sensitive to file case, conversely most Linux file systems are.

The simplest solution is to lower case all your image files on disk.

Eg.

```
find media/catalog/product -depth -exec rename 's/(.*)\/([^\/]*)/$1\/\L$2/' {} \;
```

PS. Be sure to take a backup first.